# wpf drag and drop while moving the control

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

can't seem to find how to implement behavior that supports drag&dropping a control (with DragEnter, DragOver, DragLeave and DragDrop events being fired on controls that are listening) while being able to actually drag around the control, like with Thumb control and corresponding DragDelta event. Thumb control itself and DragDrop system are mutually exclusive, as each of them requires mouse capture. So, how can i implement control that i can drag around with my mouse while still being able to drop it on something with DragDrop system?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#implementing-drag-and-drop

Comment: this explains how to implement just drag and drop, it does not explain how to support visual dragging of the control similar to Thumb control, so i can move and reposition the control around freely

Comment: basically i need similar behavior to flying windows in visual studio, unity or unreal engine, a control you can move around and drop in certain areas

Comment: "Flying windows" in VS is (or was initially) implemented somewhere in the AvalonDock. You might use it as your own UI framework. But likely huge effort to understand the mechanism and how to use it.

Comment: Specifics depend on how your app works. It's usually best to add a control and move it based on previewed mouse move event. Calculate relative position each time the event fires. Thumbs and delta don't work so well if you drag quick as you end up with a bit of lag.

Comment: I do this for dragging units onto the map for our scenario editor. Units are templated out from bound item VM in an itemscontrol so I start by adding a unit vm. The relative position to the canvas which is the itemspanel of that itemscontrol has a negative X value since you drag from a treeview to the left of the map you're dragging the unit toward. The canvas doesn't clip so the unit appears even though it's not inside the canvas.

Comment: There's no drag drop at all the way I do that. That might not suit your purposes. Or maybe it would and you could hit test to work out what control your cursor is over as you move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

idk why i haven't found this in text format anywhere, but here it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THV5BW5WW_o&ab_channel=SingletonSean
he used GiveFeedback event to implement visual control dragging while drag and drop is active, this solution fits me